# Problem with shortcut when database is included in the project

Tags: vb.net

I made a setup project and added a folder for desktop shortcut.  My application includes database file as well.  When I installed the application and ran the shortcut from desktop, it gave Desktop's path and said ABC.mdb not found.

How can I make it so that when user accesses the shortcut, it finds the database in the folder where user installed the application instead of finding it on desktop.

Thanks a lot.

Furqan

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an absolute path to the database.

Comment: but how can i know where the user will install the application?

Comment: You should store your database in the user's Application Data, regardless of the install path.  If you really don't want to, however, you can get the install path from `typeof(MyType).Assembly.Location`.

Comment: So you mean i add a folder, User's Application Data and add my database to that?

Comment: No; I mean that you should always put your database in `Path.Combine(Environment.GetSpecialFolder(Environment.SpecialFolderKind.ApplicationData), "Your App's Name\Database.mdb")`

Comment: I am sorry, I am quite new to vb.net.  I used to use vb6.  I am really not able to understand where to use the code you gave above.  When I create Setup project, I only have a few folders.  Where to put your code........ Thanks

Comment: Put that in your application as the path to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Install the .mdb file to the same directory as the .exe, then have your .exe look for the .mdb in it's own directory.

Comment: So you mean I write the code in the Menu Form (Startup form), in the load event?